# Programming Static Cells in UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm a little new to Xcode/app development

I'm currently trying to program 4 static cells in my view controller. However, when I go to run my app, the tableview doesn't show.

Here screenshot of what occurs in the ios simulator:

[image]

Here image of my tableview and its attributes in storyboard:

[image]

My SettingsViewController.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

@interface SettingsViewController : UIViewController <   MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *sidebarButton;

@end
```

My SettingsViewController.m file:

```
#import "SettingsViewController.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"

@interface SettingsViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *menuItems;

@end

@implementation SettingsViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
_sidebarButton.target = self.revealViewController;
_sidebarButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);
_sidebarButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.1f alpha:0.7f];

// Add pan gesture to hide the sidebar
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath {
if(indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0){
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myawesomeapp.com/support"]];
} else if(indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 1){
         if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
             MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
             mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
             [mailViewController setSubject:@"[My Awesome App] Support request"];
             [mailViewController setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"support@myawesomeapp.com"]];
             [self presentModalViewController:mailViewController animated:YES];
         }
          }

 }

  - (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error{
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
```

What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware static content only works with a UITableViewController as part of a storyboard. Your view controller appears to be a UIViewController subclass instead, so it will not be able to read the information from the storyboard.

I'm not sure how you've managed to get it set up like you have, but it *may* be possible just to redefine your SettingsViewController as inheriting from a table view controller instead of a plain view controller (you might have to connect the `tableView` outlet after doing this).

To change the inheritance, change this line of code:

```
@interface SettingsViewController : UIViewController <   MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

To this:

```
@interface SettingsViewController : UITableViewController <   MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

If not, you may have to drag a new table view controller onto the storyboard and set it up again with the static content.

Answer (score 0):

You should adopting the UITableViewDelegate protocol by adding the  `<UITableViewDelegate>` to your .h file.

After that, you need to connect the table view to the relevant .h or .m file and make it the delegate for the relevant table.

Anyway take a brief look at [this](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/) tutorial..

Comment: I only just need to add a UITableViewDelegate in my .h file? And then I need to connect the delegate to my view controller? I don't need to add the UITableViewDataSource?

Comment: I tried implementing the UITableViewDelegate protocol in my SettingsViewController.h and I also connected the delegate outlet of my tableview to the SettingsViewController in storyboard. Nothing happened still.

Answer (score 0):

In the storyboard size inspector, try setting height, width and origin with sufficiently large values. If that makes it visible, then play with auto stretch attributes in the same inspector (sorry, don't remember the exact names).